# install solr-4.2.1-src.tgz

Tags: java, solr

I have installed JDK 1.7 in order to run solr. 
I downloaded solr and tried the following command

```
tar xzf solr-4.2.1-src.tgz
```

There was no change here though. But what is the next step to install ? I tried extracting it but i am unsure on the steps.

After this in one of the documentation it is said to run start.jar which i again fail !!
Tried with the following one

```
java -jar start.jar
```

ERROR is -

```
Unable to access jarfile start.jar
```

By the way i was following this documentation, [Click](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-apachesolr/)

Any help, Appreciated !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the zip version: http://apache.claz.org/lucene/solr/4.2.1/solr-4.2.1.zip

```
cd /tmp
wget http://apache.claz.org/lucene/solr/4.2.1/solr-4.2.1.zip
```

Next unzip the package:

```
unzip solr-4.2.1.zip
```

Move newly created directory to /opt

```
sudo mv solr-4.2.1 /opt/
```

Then enter the newly created directory

```
cd /opt/solr-4.2.1/example/
```

There you will find an start.jar file, launch it:

```
java -jar start.jar
```

Follow this tutorial:

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_1/tutorial.html

Comment: ok let me try this....

Comment: Suggested not to install it in /tmp. By default it cleans up the directory on reboot. Can be used here /var/tmp/ instead

Comment: Correct! I forgot to mention that I normally unpack in /tmp and than move to /opt or /usr/local